# Necesito ayuda con una sentencia sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Veréis, estoy llevando a cabo un proyecto poco a poco y me he encontrado con una duda que requiere conocimientos de sql y la verdad es que conozco lo básico...

necesito que una petición ajax me haga un select que devuelva los campos de 2 tablas, pero de una de esas tablas. necesito un solo campo...

coloco la estructura

**Tabla Artista**

id | nombre | usuario | contrasena | correo | telefono | genero | localidad | descripcion | web | foto

**Tabla Evento**

id id_artista | titulo | fecha | descripcion | fecha_evento

Ambas tablas de relacionan por artista.*id* - evento.*id_artista*

Hasta el momento he probado sentencias como ...

```
SELECT * FROM artista a, evento e WHERE a.nombre =  "paco" AND e.id =26
Ésta no me valía, ya que no necesito uno en concreto, sino todos los artistas que han creado eventos... y por ello requiero de su nombre, que está en la tabla artista.

SELECT * FROM artista a, evento e;
ésta me devuelve todos los campos de ambas tablas, y yo solo necesito el nombre...
```

Quiero la tabla evento completa... y de la tabla Artista solo el nombre...
¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Os agradezco las molestias. Gracias

Comment: Hola, por favor Edita la pregunta para añadir algo más de información: ¿Has probado alguna sentencia ya? ¿Cómo no funcionó? ¿Con qué errores/dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] para más información y consejos.

Comment: el problema es que no sé como hacer esa sentencia... he probado algunas pero son erroneas en sintaxis... ya he actualizado la pregunta, de todas formas. gracias

Comment: ¿Por qué simplemente no haces `select e.*, a.campoQueQuieres ...`?

Comment: simplemente era tan facil como eso... y no se me ocurrió. gracias !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas hacer join entre las dos tablas para disponer de todos sus atributos

```
SELECT a.nombre,  e.*
FROM artista a inner join evento e on a.id_artista=e.id_artista
```

Comment: Gracias!! funcionó

Comment: @DiegoRapLow si una respuesta te ayudo, deberías marcarla correcta para que otros usuarios cuando lean a ellos también les sirva.

Comment: no lo sabia gracias ya está

Answer (score 3):

Necesitas utilizar una cláusula *JOIN*. Te dejo un [enlace con ejemplos](https://www.w3resource.com/oracle/joins/natural-join.php) que te ayudarán a entender mejor el recurso.

Tu caso es muy sencillo y con un natural join sería suficiente, aunque no ofreces mucha información (como el gestor de la base de datos, la consulta que no te funciona, etc.). La consulta puede ser algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
SQL> SELECT e.id, e.titulo, e.fecha, e.descripcion, e.fecha_evento, a.nombre
  2  FROM evento e
  3  NATURAL JOIN artista a;
```

A grosso modo sería algo así. Con más datos o tus intentos, te podría hacerla más explícita. Pero parece una consulta muy sencilla. Si no lo consigues, mejora tu pregunta y te echo una mano. De esta forma, puedes seleccionar los campos que necesites expresamente. Además como el único campo común es el id, el join se realizará en base al mismo, por lo que no tienes que especificarlo.

Adjunto también una [imagen](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Joins_del_SQL.svg) muy descriptiva de los tipos de joins que seguro te ayudará:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por la explicación!

Comment: De nada @DiegoRapLow, para ayudarnos estamos ;) Suerte con ese proyecto.